# Can GNU Autotools (Autoconf / Automake) handle Apple Mac Frameworks?

Tags: macos, autotools

The docs for GNU autotools (autoconf and automake) explain how to test for the presence of a needed library.  If the library is found, autotools will include it in LIBS to make sure any generated object files are properly linked to it.  If the library is not found, autotools can generate an error message.

For libraries, one would use the following macro:

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS(function, libraries-list, action-if-found, action-if-not-found, extra-libraries)
```

e.g.

```
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([cos], [m], [], [AC_MSG_ERROR([unable to find the cos() function in the math library])])
```

How you tell GNU autoconf / automake to do that same with a particular Apple Framework?

I probably could use the following to check whether a particular framework exists:

```
AC_CHECK_FILE(file, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found])
```

But how do I tell GNU autotools to make sure my object files are linked to a particular Apple Framework?
(My program (written in C) needs to link to the Apple `CoreServices` framework).

For manual builds on the command line, one normally would tell the compiler where to find the framework and tell it to link your object files with it.

e.g.

```
clang -o MyProgram Source.c -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework CoreServices -L/opt/local/lib -lmpeg2
```

Can GNU autotools be used when Apple Frameworks are involved?
If not, can someone suggest another tool designed to easily generate makefiles for Apple Mac software development?

Comment: I have no experience on Apple systems myself, but I found [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/index.html) to be a solid cross-platform solution several years back when I got fed up with juggling Autotools and MSVC Solutions side by side.

Comment: @DevSolar - Thanks for the suggestion.  I will definitely try out cmake.  But first I want to figure out GNU Autotools.   Given that MacOS is a proprietary OS, I suspect GNU is not too enthusiastic about adding macros to GNU autotools that are specific to MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like one can tell automake to use a specific Apple Mac Framework. It is done by adding the following into Makefile.am:

```
AM_LDFLAGS = -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework CoreServices
OR
programname_LDFLAGS = -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework CoreServices
```

And if you want to check that the Framework actually exists, one must add that check in configure.ac (presumably via using the `AC_CHECK_FILE` macro).

It is too bad that autotools does not have a macro for use in configure.ac similar to `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` that not only checks that the Framework actually exists but also adds it to a variable (e.g. FRAMEWORKS or AM_LDFLAGS) for use by automake for linking purposes. Perhaps, it could be done by creating your own M4 Macro.  M4 macros are very powerful.

P.S.  You will not need to include `-F/System/Library/Frameworks` in `AM_LDFLAGS` etc. as shown above since that is the standard search path for Frameworks on Macs.  (But you will need to include the `-F` flag if the Framework is located in a non-standard location).

No matter what, you still need to include `-framework CoreServices` in `AM-FLAGS` to make sure your program is properly linked to the Framework.  (This is no different than adding library flags (e.g. `-lmpeg2`) to make sure a required library is linked to your program during the linking stage). You should not leave that up to the user when running ./configure.

Answer (score 0):

> How you tell GNU autoconf / automake to do that same with a particular Apple Framework?

This is all about link options, and all the Autotools' usual means for dealing with compile and link options are in play.

If you are talking about using existing autotooling, then, in principle, you can specify the appropriate additional link flags in `configure`'s environment.  For example:

```
LDFLAGS='-framework CoreServices' ./configure
```

Unless the specific autotooling in question does something to break it, `./configure` will use the specified linker flags when performing library checks.  You should not then need to repeat that to `make` or have it explicitly accommodated in `Makefile.am`.

If you are *writing* the autotooling then there is all manner of things you can do, from nothing in particular (per above) to autodetecting and / or guessing to providing a `--with` or `--enable` option to allow the user to select and activate specific frameworks and framework folders and carry the appropriate link options through to `make`.  You should not need to write `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` or `AC_CHECK_LIB` invocations any differently than you otherwise would, but under some circumstances you might want to create one or more additional output variables with which to convey the link options for framework selection.

I know that's a bit vague, but so is the question.

Comment: I understand that one can over-ride the defaults specified in configure.ac when the user runs ./configure.  But that does not address my question.  Most Mac programs (like mine) rely on Apple Frameworks.  If they are not specified during the linking stage, the linking will fail.  So the required Apple Frameworks SHOULD be specified by the developer in configure.ac.  It looks like the only way to do this is by using AM_LDFLAGS in the Makefile.am (see my answer above).  And one should also check to see if the Framework exists using a macro in configure.ac.  I wish a Macro existed that did both!

Comment: @RobK, I accept that it is *desirable* for the autotooling to have built in support for frameworks, but for projects that do not, specifying `LDFLAGS` is the appropriate way to handle the situation.  And that should not be viewed as overriding defaults in such a case -- it is *adding* flags required or desired for building in a particular environment.  Flags chosen by the developer or by `configure` are communicated via different variables.

Comment: In any event, @RobK, setting `AM_LDFLAGS` in `Makefile.am` is not the same thing as specifying linker flags in `configure.ac`, and setting system-specific there literally and unconditionally is inappropriate for projects that are not Mac-specific.  As I describe in the second part of this answer, `configure` can be written to recognize Mac environments and select framework flags dynamically, with either more or less help at the command line.  You have the full power of the shell at your disposal there, plus the macro library.  But there is no standard macro specifically for framework support.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I agree that normally it is not appropriate to set  system specific settings in configure.ac especially if the project is designed to run on multiple platforms (Mac, Linux etc).  That does not apply to my project because it will only run on Mac OS due to its dependency on the CoreServices Framework.  Unfortunately, Mac Frameworks are not very portable.  I was looking for a way to easily create a Makefile.   I will give Autotools a try and set AM_FLAGS to `-framework CoreServices`. (Alternatively, I could always use Xcode).